# Declaring worksheet variable issues

Tags: vba, variables

I am trying to declare a worksheet variable as "Dim D as worksheet, set D=worksheets("shdata") and I am getting runtime error 9, subscript out of range. I dont know why this is not working, is there a problem with my code?

VBA CODE:

```
Sub unicornhorn()
'Generates user friendly graphs from raw unicorn input data

Dim columns As Integer
Dim rows As Integer
Dim Outputs(50) As String
Dim LastRow As Integer

Dim xaxis As Range
Dim yaxis As Range

Dim nLeft As Double: nLeft = 20
Dim nTop As Double: nTop = 20
Dim start As Double: start = start + 2
Dim finish As Double: finish = finish + 2


Dim Curves(14) As String
    Curves(0) = "260nm"
    Curves(1) = "280nm"
    Curves(2) = "214nm"
    Curves(3) = "Cond"
    Curves(4) = "Cond%"
    Curves(5) = "Conc"
    Curves(6) = "pH"
    Curves(7) = "Pressure"
    Curves(8) = "Flow"
    Curves(9) = "Temp"
    Curves(10) = "Fractions"
    Curves(11) = "inject"
    Curves(12) = "logbook"
    Curves(13) = "P960_Press"
    Curves(14) = "P960_Flow"

Dim D As Worksheet
Set D = Worksheets("shdata")

'defines data range
columns = shCurves.Cells(1, shCurves.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
rows = shCurves.Cells(shCurves.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For Z = 0 To columns

    'loops through array for different curves
    Outputs(Z) = shCurves.Cells(2, Z * 2 + 1).Value

    'Finds last row in column for current curve
    LastRow = Cells(D.rows.Count, Z * 2 + 1).End(xlUp).Row


    For k = 0 To 14

        'finds curve identifyer within string
        If InStr(Outputs(Z), Curves(k)) = 1 Then

        'Sets curve to proper name
        Outputs(Z) = Curves(k)


        'Plot graph
        D.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, _
        Left:=D.Range("C11").Left, _
        Top:=D.Range("C11").Top, _
        Width:=D.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 15)).Width, _
        Height:=D.Range("C11:C30").Height).Select

        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:B11")


        Exit For
        End If


    Next k

Next Z

End Sub
```

Comment: that error usually means that the sheet does not exist.  Check the spelling, and make sure that the workbook that contains that sheet is active.

Comment: Also you can alternatively use `Set D = Sheet1` if Sheet1 is the worksheet you want the D to refer to. `Sheet1` is basically the very first worksheet of any workbook.

Comment: shdata is the excel name and not the VBA name right?